# Blockquotes to display on top of div

Tags: css, html

I am having some difficulty with a blockquote element to display on top of a div I have created as my image slider. I have included a fiddle so you can see what i see.

[My demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s673j/)

Here is the code:

```
<div>
    <div class="callbacks_container">
      <ul class="rslides" id="slider4">

        <li>
        <img src="http://www.pressrecord.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/example.png" alt="">
        <div id="main-body-wrapper"> 
                <p class="caption" style="position:absolute;">  
        <span class="captionspan">
        <blockquote>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris eget leo nunc, nec tempus mi? Curabitur id nisl mi, ut vulputate urna. Quisque porta facilisis tortor, vitae bibendum velit fringilla vitae! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris eget leo nunc, nec tempus mi? Curabitur id nisl mi, ut vulputate urna. Quisque porta facilisis tortor, vitae bibendum velit fringilla vitae!
        <cite>Somebody famous</cite>
        </blockquote>   
        </span></p>
        </div>
        </li>

        <li>
        <img src="http://www.pressrecord.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/example.png" alt="">
        <div id="main-body-wrapper">
        <p class="caption" style="position:absolute;">
        <span class="captionspan"></span>
        </p>
        </div>
        </li>

        <li>
        <img src="img/nurseriesbig.jpg" alt="">
        <div id="main-body-wrapper">
        <p class="caption" style="position:absolute;">
        <span class="captionspan"></span>
        </p>
        </div>
        </li>

        <li><img src="http://www.pressrecord.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/example.png" alt="">
        <div id="main-body-wrapper">
        <p class="caption" style="position:absolute;">
        <span class="captionspan"></span>
        </p>
        </div>
        </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: You'll need to elaborate on what exactly this "difficulty" is.

Comment: Explain what your exact problem is

Answer (score 1):

Here **Fiddle**:  http://jsfiddle.net/Anee/s673j/1/

Add this to css:

```
 blockquote {
     position:absolute;
 }
 blockquote:after{
    content: "\201D";
    margin-right: -2.75em;
 }
```

Not sure, why you have `p class caption` in the middle. you might want to remove it.

Comment: See that is perfect - you also see the white semi-transparent box? How would I be able to apply the blockquote to sit inside of that?

Comment: Well, you have to place the blockquote inside it. and apply all styling according to class caption

Comment: You can't have blockquote inside p, but you can have p inside blockquote. Also, you are using same `id's on div's`. `ID's` have to be `unique`

Comment: Would you suggest I turn them into classes?

Comment: Yes. do that and place the p inside the blockquote or remove it completely